# Given a journal error and a lsusb listing identify usb device causing the problem

Tags: usb

In arch linux the journal shows this error message

```
 kernel: usb 2-2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
```

Given this listing of devices (lsusb), which is the problematic one?

```
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
 Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
 Bus 001 Device 004: ID 278b:3001 ROTEL Rotel PC-USB
 Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
 Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2109:8817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB Billboard Device   
 Bus 001 Device 025: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub
 Bus 001 Device 044: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub
 Bus 001 Device 045: ID 058f:6254 Alcor Micro Corp. USB Hub
 Bus 001 Device 046: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
 Bus 001 Device 047: ID 058f:6254 Alcor Micro Corp. USB Hub
 Bus 001 Device 048: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
 Bus 001 Device 049: ID 30fa:0300  USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
 Bus 001 Device 050: ID 1a2c:4094 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd USB Keyboard
 Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
 Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
 Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
 Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
 Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 0):

> Given this listing of devices (lsusb), which is the problematic one?

None. The error you get says "can't even talk to the device enough to get it to cooperate on the bus, let alone get it's vendor and product IDs"

Lsusb hence won't show that device: it's literally not on the bus.

Note that the error actually points out the problematic device is attached to port 1 of the hub that's device 2 on the second bus. That however didn't tell you whether this is an external or internal USB port, and if external, which physical port that logical port 1 corresponds to.

Comment: All USB devices are working so... what could the trouble be?